# Slowness while deleting large amount of data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables [AssetPhoto] and [AssetPhoto_Backup] and have to delete some records, say 7 million, from [AssetPhoto] based on [AssetPhoto_Backup] table.

The table structure was very simple

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssetPhoto](
    [PhotoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssetNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhotoCaption] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhotoContent] [image] NULL,
    [PhotoCaptured] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastEditDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Structure of [AssetPhoto_Backup] table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssetPhoto_Backup](
    [PhotoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssetNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhotoCaption] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhotoContent] [image] NULL,
    [PhotoCaptured] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastEditDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

the query for deletion is

```
declare @i int =0; 



while(@i<=700) 

begin 

delete top(10000) a  from AssetPhoto a  join AssetPhoto_Backup ab 
on ab.photoid=a.photoid  

set @i=@i+1; 

end
```

Both have clustered index.When I tried to improve the performance using tuning advisor of MSSQl, it didn't give any recommendation.Both tables have PhotoId as PK.

How can I improve the query performance?Why the process speed slows down as the process goes on.Thanks in advance for the answers.

I have one more query,

```
    declare @i int =0; 



        while(@i<=700) 

        begin 

       delete  a from AssetPhoto a 
where a.photoid  in(select Top 10000 Suba.photoid
         from AssetPhoto Suba join AssetPhoto_Backup subab
         on subab.photoid=suba.photoid)

        set @i=@i+1; 

        end
```

Which one gives better performance?I am not that much of expert in SQL server.So, please anyone help me to understand the difference between these two queries?

Comment: What's the percentage of rows deleted?

Comment: Total 9 million rows are there.From which,I have to delete 7 million records based on a condition

Comment: Coming from a Datawarehouse background, for deleting a large percentage of rows I prefer to: create a new table, Insert the remaining rows (`SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`), drop old & rename new to old table. Should be much more efficient :-)

Comment: Yes, it was a good idea.but we don't have much space in the drive where the ldf and mdf files of this database reside.So I have created a new database in another drive and moved that 7 million data to that table(ie, AssetPhoto_Backup).So I am not able to do the insert for remaining rows and drop the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit your deletes after every batch, so the transaction log doesn't need to grow.

Also, I have decreased the batch size and increased the number of loops, so the batches will be smaller and commited more often, putting less load on the transaction log.

```
declare @i int =0; 

while(@i<=7000)    
begin 

  begin transaction;

  delete top(1000) a  
  from AssetPhoto a  
       join AssetPhoto_Backup ab on ab.photoid=a.photoid;

  commit transaction;

  set @i=@i+1;     
end
```

Comment: But the recovery model of the database has been changed to Simple.So how the deletion process is affected by the transaction log?

Comment: The transaction log main purpose is to log transactions so they can be rolled back, not only for restoring databases to any arbitrary prior state. Even on simple mode your transaction log will need to store all the records deleted (in case you have to rollback). As a rule of thumb, the shorter the transaction, the less stress you put on the database.

Comment: Now I understood.I thought that if we change the transaction log, it wouldn't record any transaction logs.Then, what is the advantage of using simple recovery model over full recovery model?

Comment: In Full Recovery Model you would be able to restore your database to any prior point you chose, and not only rollback just the current transaction.

Comment: I got one more suggestion from another post,WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
begin transaction;
delete top(10000) a  from AssetPhoto a  join AssetPhoto_Backup ab 
    on ab.photoid=a.photoid  

   IF @@ROWCOUNT < 10000  BREAK;
commit transaction;

END, If I change the while loop like this, is there any performance improvement can I expect?

Comment: No, the improvement is the same : commiting every batch of deletes. It only changes the form of the loop to launch them. In this code it doesn't delete just 7M records, it deletes all of them.